# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column COLUMN_id violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Newbie here both on Stackoverflow as well as django/drf.

I am receiving this error, I know that I can solve this by adding the null field in the calendar foreign key file. However, I can not modify the field due to some reason, how can I fix this? Please let me know if other info is required.

Error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "instructor_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Model:

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
    instructor = models.ForeignKey('Instructor', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Serializer:

```
class CalendarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Calendar
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Traceback -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/intenal/zion/scheduler/views.py", line 541, in calendar
    calendar_object = serializer.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 205, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 939, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "instructor_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1357, dance, 2021-12-17, friday, null, batch, 6-9, online, 1, 1, 12:51:19, 13:51:22, null, null, f, null).
```

Instructor Views:

```
    if request.method == 'GET':
        category = request.query_params.get('category')
        style = request.query_params.get('style')

        instructors = Instructor.objects.all()
        if pk:
            instructors = instructors.filter(id=pk)
        if category:
            instructors = instructors.filter(category=category)
        if style:
            instructors = instructors.filter(style__name=style)

        serializers = InstructorSerializer(instructors, many=True)
        return Response(serializers.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.data.get('id'):
            return Response({'message': 'Id is not expected here'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        serializer = InstructorSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            instructor_object = serializer.save()
            instructor_id = instructor_object.id
            return Response({
                'id': instructor_id,
                'message': f'Instructor added successfully with ID {instructor_id}'
            },
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Calendar view:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.data.get('id'):
            return Response({'message': 'Id is not expected here'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        serializer = CalendarSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            calendar_object = serializer.save()
            calendar_id = getattr(calendar_object, 'id')
            return Response({
                'id': calendar_id,
                'message': 'Calendar inserted successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

instructor serializer:

```
class InstructorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Instructor
        fields = ['id', 'is_active', 'name', 'category', 'style']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep["style"] = StyleSerializer(instance.style.all(), many=True).data # TODO: Change this to contain only active styles
        return rep
```

Comment: When did you get this error, while migrating your changes or using serializer?

Comment: while using the serializer

Comment: Also Mention the payload you are posting to your serializer.

Comment: @SukhpreetSingh I am not posting anything to my serializer, but yeah it is failing at the point where I am doing serializer.is_valid. Added the traceback if it helps

Comment: if nothing is posted to your serializer or no data is provided and you call is_valid() on serializer a null value is supplied to the model field which gives you the integrity error.

Comment: how can i fix this now? how is_valid could be called on GET request?

Comment: You need a payload as `{"instructor": 1}` and the value of instructor should be a valid primary key for your instructor so when you run serializer.is_valid() return true.

Comment: @berkeeb could you please explain to me a little bit more, I didn't understood the passing payload bit, but it seems like this is not what I could or should do

Comment: can you add the view to you question, may be then its evident why the error occurs for the get request.

Comment: @SukhpreetSingh added both instructor and calendar view as well

Comment: the get request is  fine. the only problematic thing i can see in the stacktrace is when trying to  create calendar the intructor id is not passed in the data due to which integrity error is coming

Answer (score 0):

You did not give the Instructor serializer so I can not talk about it. For your `CalendarView`, when you create a model serializer for your `Calendar` model, drf converts it to something like:

```py
class CalenderSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    instructor = serializer.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Instructor.objects.all())
    other_fields...
```

So `request.data` has to include `instructor` key with a value of valid primary key for your instructor in POST method.

Comment: '''class InstructorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Instructor
        fields = ['id', 'is_active', 'name', 'category', 'style']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep["style"] = StyleSerializer(instance.style.all(), many=True).data # TODO: Change this to contain only active styles
        return rep

Comment: So in which view you get an error. Isn’t it CalenderView ?